# Content-Disposition filename in Chinese not supported

Tags: java, file, character-encoding, http-headers, httpresponse

I have been trying to download attachment with Chinese filename but somehow their encoding changes while downloading and some gibberish filename is saved where there are Chinese chararchters.

Technology: Java
Server: Apache Tomcat

This is what I've tried already

`response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="7_6_4_AM__2017_JS_003_南通凤凰服装_B1_108"");`

Output(Downloaded attachment name): "7_6_4_AM__2017_JS_003_W_äð"

I've also tried appending * to filename directive after referring to :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

`response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename*="7_6_4_AM__2017_JS_003_南通凤凰服装_B1_108"");`

Output(Downloaded attachment name): "706.txt"

Also,

In my research I found that HTTP header messages cannot carry characters outside the ISO-8859-1 character set.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5987

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to set character encoding:

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

You might also want to encode your filename first:

```
filename= URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8");
```

From the [document](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setCharacterEncoding-java.lang.String-)

> Sets the character encoding (MIME charset) of the response being sent
>   to the client, for example, to UTF-8. If the character encoding has
>   already been set by setContentType(java.lang.String) or
>   setLocale(java.util.Locale), this method overrides it. Calling
>   setContentType(java.lang.String) with the String of text/html and
>   calling this method with the String of UTF-8 is equivalent with
>   calling setContentType with the String of text/html; charset=UTF-8.
>   This method can be called repeatedly to change the character encoding.
>   **This method has no effect if it is called after getWriter has been
>   called or after the response has been committed.**

Comment: Already tried response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");Let me check with fileName encoding.

Comment: Did you encode your filename? Did you setCharacterEncoding before calling to `getWriter()`?

Comment: Just remember to decode the filename after receiving the response. I forgot that.